# How do I make a lambda query nullable?

Tags: c#, lambda

I am getting the following error:

> The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized
>   value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query
>   must use a nullable type.

How do I make my lambda expression nullable ?

```
d.QtyOnOrder = db.DieOrders.Where(c=>c.DrawDie.SizeUS==d.SizeUS).Sum(c => c.QtyOpen);
```

Update:  The code below works.  Can someone tell me why the Linq expression works and the Lambda does not ?

```
            var dies = from e in db.DieOrders
                          where e.DrawDieID == d.ID && e.QtyOpen !=null
                          select e;


            var _qtyOpen = dies.Sum(x => x.QtyOpen);
```

Comment: Is `d.QtyOnOrder` nullable?

Comment: Whats the datatype of "QtyOnOrder"?

Comment: It is a nullable int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like @RezaRahmati's suggestion, but an alternative is:

```
d.QtyOnOrder = db.DieOrders.Where(c=>c.DrawDie.SizeUS==d.SizeUS && d.QtyOpen.HasValue)
    .Sum(c => c.QtyOpen);
```

If all of the `QtyOpen` are null, then you are summing an empty list which will give you zero.

What I like about Reza's answer however, is that it makes it more explicit that you will set the result to zero if the sum is null.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is `QtyOnOrder`, since `Sum` can returns null `QtyOnOrder` should be nullable or use this syntax:

```
d.QtyOnOrder = db.DieOrders.Where(c=>c.DrawDie.SizeUS==d.SizeUS).Sum(c => c.QtyOpen) ?? 0;
```

Comment: I tried this and I get the following: The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to cast as well, for example the following;

```
d.QtyOnOrder = db.DieOrders.Where(c=>c.DrawDie.SizeUS==d.SizeUS)
.Sum(c => (int?)c.QtyOpen) ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that `d.QtyOnOrder` is not nullable so the solution is to change the class definition so that it is an `int?` (short hand for `Nullable<int>`) or to use the null coalescing operator on the left hand side to ensure that null is never returned;

```
db.DieOrders.Where(c=>c.DrawDie.SizeUS==d.SizeUS).Sum(c => c.QtyOpen) ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the datatype of "QtyOnOrder" is **int**, You should make it as **int?**. So now even if sum returns null, code do not generate any error.

**int?** is a nullable datatype. To know about Nullable types Visit [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).